# vb.net two BindingSource for two DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a form with two DataGridViews and two BindingSources
This is a vb.net project on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2019
Here is where things go wrong. When I do an Edit Columns on dgvTwo where I remove all the Columns this causes both DataGridViews to load nothing
The first DataGridView (dgvData) never had Columns Added with the RIGHT CLICK routine
But if I use Add Columns by RIGHT CLICK Add Columns to dgvTwo and run the code here is a screen shot
**The Question is how to load the data in two DataGridViews with two BindingSources?**
And the Code is Below

```
Public Class frmOne

Private Sub frmOne_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim table1 As New DataTable
    Dim table2 As New DataTable

    With table1.Columns
        .Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Name", GetType(String))
    End With

    With table1.Rows
        .Add(1, "Peter")
        .Add(2, "Paul")
        .Add(3, "Mary")
    End With

    With table2.Columns
        .Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Word", GetType(String))
    End With
    With table2.Rows
        .Add(1, "Bob")
        .Add(2, "Carol")
        .Add(3, "Alice")
    End With
    'This code works if you do not use table2 code
    'dgvTwo.Rows.Add(1, "Bob")
    'dgvTwo.Rows.Add(2, "Carol")
    'dgvTwo.Rows.Add(3, "Alice")

    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dgvTwo.Columns
        column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    Next

    dgvTwo.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 15)
    dgvTwo.Columns(0).Width = 100
    dgvTwo.Columns(1).Width = 150

    dgvData.GridColor = Color.Red
    dgvData.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None
    dgvData.BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray

    dgvData.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkGray
    dgvData.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black
    dgvData.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.[True]

    dgvData.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    dgvData.AllowUserToResizeColumns = False

    dgvData.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
    dgvData.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray

    Me.bsOne.DataSource = table1
    Me.dgvData.DataSource = Me.bsOne

    Me.bsTwo.DataSource = table2
    Me.dgvTwo.DataSource = Me.bsTwo

End Sub
Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    Using dialogue As New frmTwo
        Dim selectedRecord = DirectCast(Me.bsOne.Current, DataRowView)

        'Pass the initial data into the dialogue.
        dialogue.TextBoxText = CStr(selectedRecord("Name"))

        'Display the modal dialogue.
        If dialogue.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            'The user clicked OK so get the final data from the dialogue.
            selectedRecord("Name") = dialogue.TextBoxText
            Me.bsOne.EndEdit()
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Screen Shot

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: The Load events eats up exceptions. Move that code somewhere else, to better identify the exception. -- You don't need to add Columns in the DGV Designer, but the Columns are of course generated after you have set the DataSource, you cannot reference Columns before that point. So, first set the DGVs DataSource, then configure the Columns (as in `dgvTwo.Columns(0).Width = 100`). Or, add the Columns in the Designer and set each Column's `DataPropertyName` to the corresponding Column name in your DataTable(s). If the structure of the DataTables doesn't change, it's probably a good choice.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks YES I am mixing design and data  adding concepts Need to not do this grammatically I am making work for myself End Goal is use BindingSource connected to a SQLite Table Will Try writing a Sub that is called from Form Load still real new to VB.Net

Comment: Isn't Ted supposed to be in with Bob and Carol and Alice? ;-)

Comment: @Mary He told me he was at your house helping walk the dog and playing Bridge